# Rails Newby: Strong parameters in Rails 5 not letting specified parameter Through - HABTM

Tags: has-and-belongs-to-many, strong-parameters, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm new to rails, and I'm currently trying to develop an API based app using Rails 5, on one of my controllers I have a function to filter the allow parameters like so

```
def provider_params
  params.require(:provider).permit(:name, :phone, :email, :website, :address, :provider_id, :bio, :specialty_ids => [])
end
```

Then posting from Paw I noticed that the arguments that are not attributes of the table are no included in **provider_params**, the parameter I'm supposed to receive is an array, which is defined by a HABTM relation-ship.

This is how my models look like

***specialty.rb***

```
class Specialty < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :providers
end
```

***provider.rb***

```
class Provider < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :specialties  
end
```

And this is how the join table was created via migration

```
class CreateProvidersSpecialties < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :providers_specialties, :id => false do |t|
        t.integer :provider_id
        t.integer :specialty_id 
    end

    add_index :providers_specialties, :provider_id
    add_index :providers_specialties, :specialty_id
  end
end
```

The JSON I'm posting

```
{
  "name": "the name",
  "specialty_ids": [
    1,
    2
  ]
}
```

So as I mentioned, the array **specialty_ids** doesn't seem to be coming through, and even if it did, I suspect there's still something else I need to do in order for rails to insert the content of **specialty_ids** in the **ProvidersSpecialties** Table

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was finally solved by removing the `requir` call from the method `provider_params`, since I wasn't wrapping the `json-payload` in a `provider` key. Apparently once you add the `require(:key)` call you would only be able to add parameters that belong to the Model, which is weird since an error should be raised when the key is not present, what was the case with my payload, lacking the `provider` key.